# AdView No longer has setGravity?

Tags: java, android, admob

Just updated to the new Android SDK Rev 22.3 with Android 4.4 support. After that I see AdView doesn't have a `setGravity` method anymore.

I need this as i'm making a Unity3D plugin and can't use XML markup.

**EDIT: I'm trying to align the AdView to either the BottomLeft, BottomCenter, TopLeft, ect, ect...  So any other way to do it would be helpful as Java on Android isn't my typical environment I use.**

Comment: This has nothing to do with ADT and/or Android 4.4, but rather with updating to the latest [Google Play Services 4.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html). With that, `AdView` no longer extends `RelativeLayout` (which offers the `setGravity()` method). In stead, it extends `ViewGroup` directly, which means you're out of luck here, regardless of whether you're doing things in code or xml... Perhaps you could elaborate a bit on what you're trying to achieve? Some code with desired outcome as a mockup/sketch might help.

Comment: @MH. I'm trying to align the AdView to either the BottomLeft, BottomCenter, TopLeft, ect, ect...

Comment: If you're trying to position the `AdView` in a layout (as opposed to positioning the content inside the `AdView`), then you should be setting that on the parent/layout params of `AdView`, not the `AdView` itself.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution for that. I previously relied on the setGravity method. To get the same thing I do it in this way:

```
/// Create a AdView
AdView myAdView = new AdView(MY_ACTIVITY);
myAdView.setAdUnitId(<ADMOB ID>);
myAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

/// Set the initial frame
FrameLayout.LayoutParams initialFrm = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                                   FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                                   Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP); 
MY_ACTIVITY.addContentView(myAdView, initialFrm);

/// ....

/// Now whenever I want to position it on the bottom I do this:
myAdView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                         Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM));

/// To put it back on the top, do this:
myAdView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                         Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP));
```

Comment: Basically, use FrameLayout, because you can set the Gravity flags for it.

Comment: Tnx, i'll be giving this a go later.  I moved back to the old AdMob for now.  But plan on updating soon.